# Wrapper/adverb to suppress messages in R

Tags: r

A lot of tidyverse functions are very verbose with their messages, leading to logs that are full of stuff like

```
New names:
* `` -> ...1
* `` -> ...2
* `` -> ...3
* `` -> ...4
* `` -> ...5
```

repeated a zillion times. This makes reviewing actual warning messages very difficult.

Is there a drop-in (a) wrapper function that will suppress messages generated from code run inside of it or (b) an adverb that turns a function into one that doesn't generate messages? I'm hoping for a simple modification I can make for my code once it's stable and I don't need to look at all the messages from a particularly verbose line. `purrr::quietly` is almost what I want, but because it returns the original output as part of a list it's not truly a drop-in replacement or wrapper for an unmodified line of code.

Comment: There is a reason why you get those warning/messages. You should find and fix them instead of suppressing them.

Comment: Hi @RonakShah, thank you for the advice. I do believe it is usually better to fix warnings rather than suppress them. But some package authors believe in very verbose message behavior in which functions report what they are doing, which can fill up the message stream with cruft - especially when said functions are part of a pipeline that is being repeated hundreds of times. I want to be able to quiet these functions when I choose to, precisely *so* that I can pay attention to the important warnings that arise elsewhere in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`suppressMessages()` does what you are looking for.

```r
a <- data.frame(a=1,a=2, check.names = FALSE)

tibble::as_tibble(a, .name_repair = "universal")
#> New names:
#> * a -> a...1
#> * a -> a...2
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   a...1 a...2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2

suppressMessages({
  tibble::as_tibble(a, .name_repair = "universal")
})
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   a...1 a...2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2
```

It also works with the pipe `%>%`.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE) 
tibble::as_tibble(a, .name_repair = "universal") %>% 
  suppressMessages()
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   a...1 a...2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2
```